# apply a function of package moonsun in R

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to all the 334 rows of data frame M, which contains time and position data and get one value for each row. Instead, I get a list of 334 values for each row. How can I simply get one value per row calculated from the values of the variables of that same row?

These are the head and the tail of data frame M:

```
d mo    y   lat  long
 5  6 2007    NA    NA
 6  6 2007    NA    NA
 7  6 2007    NA    NA
 8  6 2007 26.89 15.53
 9  6 2007 28.00 15.73
10  6 2007 22.41 14.93
...
26  4 2008 23.86 14.05
27  4 2008 24.12 14.34
28  4 2008 27.75 12.87
29  4 2008 27.28 10.91
30  4 2008 24.17 14.44
1  5 2008    NA    NA
```

My code:

```
f1 = function(x){
         options(latitude= M$lat, longitude= M$long); 
         as.lt(moon.rst(jday = jd(M$y,M$mo,M$d)))
}
M$rs <- apply(M, 1, f1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f1  <- function(d, mo, y, lat, long){
  options(latitude = lat, longitude = long)
  as.lt(moon.rst(jday = jd(y, mo, d)))
}
data$rs <- do.call(f1, data)
Warning message:
In if (year < 0) c = floor((365.25 * year) - 0.75) else c = floor(365.25 *  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
data
   d mo    y   lat  long     rs.rise  rs.transit      rs.set
1  8  6 2007 26.89 15.53  0h 24m 30s  5h 42m  2s 11h 42m 13s
2  9  6 2007 28.00 15.73  1h  4m 42s  6h 34m  5s 12h 46m 30s
3 10  6 2007 22.41 14.93  1h 54m 38s  7h 31m  8s 13h 53m 59s
```

There is a warning from the function `jd()` since we are passing vectors (in this case `year`) as an argument, but despite this I hope that is the result that you need.

Edit: Another version without any warnings, using `apply`, but using indices and it seemed for me that `do.call` is faster.

```
f1 <- function(M){
  options(latitude= M[4], longitude= M[5]); 
  as.lt(moon.rst(jday = jd(M[3],M[2],M[1])))
}
apply(data[,c('d','mo','y','lat','long')], 1, f1)
[[1]]
                  rise     transit         set
2005-06-08  6h  2m 30s 13h  8m  3s 20h 12m 51s

[[2]]
                  rise     transit         set
2005-06-09  6h 55m 34s 14h  1m 26s 21h  4m 44s

[[3]]
                  rise     transit         set
2005-06-10  8h  7m 41s 14h 57m  7s 21h 43m 36s
```

Comment: Thanks Julius, unfortunately either of them work. When using apply I get 2 warnings, the one you mentioned and this one: non-unique values when setting row-names, '2007-09-30-Moon', '2007-12-31-Moon'...When using do.call I get this warning: the argument was not used (jul= c(13669,13670...). It seems we're pretty close though. I could send you the original data frame which has 37 variables

Comment: Strange, I manage to get these two errors but only when using do.call. Ok, upload that data frame somewhere, I will check it.

Comment: I don't have access to a ftp. Would dropbox or an e-mail work for you?

Comment: I finally used pastebi.ca. This is the URL:http://pastebin.ca/2169429. It's a dput(). Hope it works

Comment: Ok! I haven't tried with the whole data frame but I think I figured out what happened: you have to pass the arguments inside [ ] exactly in the same order you have them in the data frame; it won't identify them just by their labels. Thank you very much for your help and your time, Julius

Comment: You are right, that is what I did. The problem is that `apply` takes every row as a vector and it does not have columns, so we can not use these names `d`,`mo`...

Comment: Thank you Julius, the answer worked fine for me. I wasn't aware I had this question still going on. Sorry for the inconveniences.